# How do I show the jQuery data value in the given format HTML list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How can I print the jQuery values as the HTML format list?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="comment author-comment">
  <div class="info">
    <a href="#">Jack Smith</a>
    <span>3 hours ago</span>
  </div>
  <a class="avatar" href="#">
    <img src="{{ asset('commentui/images/avatar_author.jpg') }}" width="35" alt="Profile Avatar" title="Jack Smith" />
  </a>
  <p>JQuery value is here.</p>
</li>
```

```js
jQuery('#comntRetrive').click(function(e){
  $.get('{{ URL::to('comment/retrive') }}', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
jQuery('#comntRetrive').click(function(e){
    $.get('{{ URL::to('comment/retrive') }}',function(data){
        console.log(data); // to check the data
        $('.comment p').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use JQuery, you can do something like that :

**HTML**

```
<p id="value-container">JQuery value is here.</p>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('#comntRetrive').click(function(e){
   $.get('{{ URL::to('comment/retrive') }}',function(data){
       $('#value-container').text(data);
   });
});
```

Hope it helped.

*Edit*

As **dm707** said, using .html() instead of .text() will treat is as HTML and not plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You should set id for p tag

```
<p id="pcontainer">JQuery value is here.</p>
```

then you can

```
jQuery('#comntRetrive').click(function(e){
   $.get('{{ URL::to('comment/retrive') }}',function(data){
       $('#pcontainer').append('<div>'+data+'</div');
   });
});
```

append make you able to use html tags too
or if its just text use:

```
$('#pcontainer').text(data);
```

Comment: I don't know why do you stretch the process by adding `id` and then while appending also, you are adding data inside `div`. simply it can be done. see my answer

Comment: @JitendraAhuja yes I know we don't need `div` ....but I said if you he want to use html tag's too with data he can use append and `div` is sample

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your data wherever you want in a DOM using .html() or .text()

```
jQuery('#comntRetrive').click(function(e){
   $.get('{{ URL::to('comment/retrive') }}',function(data){
       $('#value-container').html(data);
   });
});`
```